# Display settings changes automatically with dual monitors in 12.04 and 12.10 AMD

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, 12.10

Dual monitors works fine, except that the settings suddenly change. This happens very often, sometimes several times in a few minutes. It is very irritating having to set the settings again each time. Suddenly mirroring is set to on, sometimes the monitor switch places (from left to right and so on), and most of the times the screen resolutions are also changed.

I use Gnome Shell. I have tried unity with the same result. I use an open driver. I have earlier used fglrx, with some better results (still happens, but not so often), but can't install it sucsessfully after upgrading to ubuntu 12.10.

I know there is a similar question about this issue, but it's not answered. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with dual monitors as well in Ubuntu 12.04.
It turned out that my graphics card did not support 3D acceleration features and after deactivating any proprietary drivers and using unity2D instead of regular unity, the monitors are working without any problems.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. It made me think differently: I searched for how to get 3D acceleration with the open driver. It turned out that all I needed to do was to install the 3.6 kernel, as Ubuntu 12.10 already supports all the other stuff needed for 3D acceleration. I haven't tested with two monitors yet, but I hope it works. If it does, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Seems like the opengl is linked to the intel graphics card and not the amd (AMD/Intel hybrid)...